# WiFi not working any more since editing a file in /etc/modprobe.d

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, kernel

The story started when I tried to solve the well known conflict between wifi and Bluetooth (Ubuntu 14.04.5 ).

I found a potential solution on an Ubuntu forum and applied it.

The command :

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0 auto_agg=0 swcrypto=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf > /dev/null
```

After rebooting, no way to get the wifi working.
Numerous researches on the web didn't help me at all.

I installed another 14.04 Ubuntu alongside the original one and booting with that new one makes the Wifi work, so the hardware is 100% ok.

Then I upgraded the original, "no working wifi", 14.04 to 16.04 and same problem, cannot get wifi working.
`ifconfig wlan0 down` and `up` have been tried several times also.

Worth saying that `eth0` (with cable) 
gives me network connection.

```
$ ifconfig
eth0
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:6a:8a:92:88:77  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:17 

lo   
      Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:532 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:532 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:41984 (41.9 KB)  TX bytes:41984 (41.9 KB)

wlan0
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:f7:33:55:0a:46  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  12
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
arc4                   16384  2
iwldvm                233472  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo 
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
mac80211              737280  1 iwldvm
acer_wmi               20480  0
cdc_mbim               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
cdc_wdm                20480  2 cdc_mbim
videodev              176128  4   uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
cdc_ncm                32768  1 cdc_mbim
intel_rapl             20480  0
usbnet                 45056  2 cdc_mbim,cdc_ncm
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_intel
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
bluetooth             520192  39 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  3 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  3 snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  18    snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
cryptd                 20480  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
mei_me                 36864  0
dell_smo8800           16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
lpc_ich                24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
cuse                   16384  3
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915                 1208320  3
tg3                   163840  0
psmouse               126976  0
ptp                    20480  1 tg3
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 i915
ahci                   36864  4
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   364544  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
wmi                    20480  1 acer_wmi
fjes                   28672  0
video                  40960  2 i915,acer_wmi
```

---

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
               Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
               Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
               Power Management:off

wwp0s26u1u1c2  no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions
```

---

```
$ lshw
   *-network
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 0
             bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
             logical name: wlan0
             version: 24
             serial: c8:f7:33:55:0a:46
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list  ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-38-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
             resources: irq:30 memory:f1500000-f1501fff
```

---

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.

remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs     /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

# options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
# options iwlwifi swcrypto=1
# options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8

# options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8

# options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

If anyone could be of any help, will be greatly appreciated,

Edit: Just to avoid confusion, wireless was working before using command

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0 auto_agg=0 swcrypto=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading `dmesg` output line by line I have found out that I had a file `badiwlwifi.conf` stored in `/etc/modprobe.d`. I did a copy of the bad config file right after the problem.

Seems that having `iwlwifi` in the file is enough to be taken into consideration at boot time.
I learned something today.

Comment: Actually, I think any file that ends in `.conf` is used.